# Merging lists on matching element

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function to merge two pair lists, in this case each element containing a character and a number.

```
mergeTupleList [] blist = blist
mergeTupleList alist [] = []
mergeTupleList (a:ab:as) (b:bn:bs) =
    if ab == b
        then a:[] ++ bn:[] ++ mergeTupleList (a:ab:as) (bs)
        else [] ++ mergeTupleList (as) (b:bn:bs)

listA = [('a',1),('b',1),('a',2),('b',1)] 
listZ = [('b',1),('z',1),('b',1),('z',2)]
```

It seems that in the 'else' case (b:bn:bs) is not the whole pair list loaded in the beginning, but the short version (bs) because it has been filtered by the 'then' condition. 
I'm looking for a way to transmit the original (b:bn:bs) list to this function.

input and output:

```
*Main> mergeTupleList ListA ListZ
[('a',1),('z',1),('a',1),('z',2)]
```

expected output:

```
[('a',1),('z',1),('a',1),('z',2),('a',2),('z',1),('a',2),('z',2)]
```

For clarification :

> Perhaps merging is not the adequate word. For every (second) element in `ListA` existing in the original `ListZ` write the element following it.

Another example:

```
ListA = [1,0,3,0]
ListZ = [0,8,0,9]

*Main> mergeTupleList listA listZ 
[1,8,1,9]
```

expected output:
`[1,8,1,9,3,8,3,9]`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly the function should be doing? Your expected output with given `listA` and `listZ` isn't quite what I would expect from merging two lists.

Comment: Perhaps merging is not the adequate word. For every (second) element in ListA existing in the original ListZ write the element following it.

Comment: You should probably edit this into the question itself.

Comment: Could you give a better example without pairs? At the moment, your, your example doesn't really make sense. The second element in `listA` is `('b',1)`. It exists in `listZ`, so the following element is `('z',1)`. However, now there's apparently another `('a',1)` in your expected output, but it doesn't exist in the second list at all, and doesn't come up in the first list twice.

Comment: Maybe you are calling the wrong function? 
`concatTupleList` ≠ `mergeTupleList`

Comment: @WardVa, err sorry, I fixed the name. I renamed the function before posting.

Comment: That a look at the question, I edited another example. We take the same `('a',1)` because there are two `('b',1)` in `ListZ`. Imagine it as `('a',1)` goes to `('z',1)` through `('b',1)` but `('a',1)` also goes to  `('z',2)` through `('b',1)`. @Zeta

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: you're trying to traverse your lists from left to right, and if a traversed element of `listA` is not in `listZ`, retain it, otherwise retain the corresponding element of `listZ`. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: You seem to scan ListA and listZ in lockstep, so the number of elements in the result is the same as for the source list(s). Your examples show that you have to re-scan ListZ from start for each second element of ListA.

Comment: If this was a graph I want to show that there is a way from `('a',1)` to `('z',1)` but I also want to show that there is a way from `('a',1)` to `('z',2)` since all three are connected to `('b',1)` ; `('b',1)` is the connector from one list to another . Traverse `listA` from left to right yes, if a traversed element of `listA` is not in `listZ` do nothing. If it is, retain it's precursor in `ListA` + it's follower in `listZ`

Comment: Yes, I understood this but I don't know how... @9000

Comment: To traverse two lists at once one can `zip` them together and then work with the result. If you need to access also previous/next elements, zip the list with itself with one element added/dropped respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a series of solutions for you. First, the following produces the desired output. I think this is as specified, but note that `mergeTupleList'`
no longer returns the bList in it's first line. That wasn't performing as expected, although your description leads me to believe that you do want that.

The secret to this solution is the inclusion of the subfunction `tupleAB`, which does all the tupling for the first `a:ab`, consuming the entire `bs` list before evaluating the next `ab` pair for the whole `bs` list.

```
mergeTupleList' [] _ = []
mergeTupleList' alist [] = []
mergeTupleList' (a:ab:as) bbnbs =
  let
    tupleAB (b:bn:bs) = 
      if ab == b
         then a:[] ++ bn:[] ++ tupleAB bs 
         else [] ++ tupleAB bs 
    tupleAB _ = []
  in tupleAB bbnbs ++ mergeTupleList' as bbnbs
```

Next is a slight cleanup of all those naughty `:[] ++`

```
mergeTupleList'' [] _ = []
mergeTupleList'' alist [] = []
mergeTupleList'' (a:ab:as) bbnbs =
  let
    tupleAB (b:bn:bs) = 
      if ab == b
         then a : bn : tupleAB bs 
         else tupleAB bs 
    tupleAB _ = []
  in tupleAB bbnbs ++ mergeTupleList'' as bbnbs
```

The above solutions have some dangling case expressions. What do we do in the case where one of the lists isn't even numbered? If we instead turn each first two terms into a pair, we have lists of pairs (of pairs). This conversion function changes your lists.

```
pairListCvt :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairListCvt (a:b:cs) = (a,b) : pairListCvt cs
pairListCvt (a:[]) = [] --maybe should be error?
pairListCvt _ = []

listACvt = pairListCvt listA 
listZCvt = pairListCvt listZ
```

Now, rewritten again, we have less unmatched patterns, and so probably less chance for error. This is an example of selecting a type to provide a bit of safety; type safety.

```
mergeTupleList''' [] _ = []
mergeTupleList''' alist [] = []
mergeTupleList''' ((a,ab):as) bbnbs =
  let
    tupleAB ((b,bn):bs) = 
      if ab == b
         then (a , bn) : tupleAB bs 
         else mergeTupleList''' as ((b,bn):bs)
    tupleAB _ = []
  in tupleAB bbnbs ++ mergeTupleList''' as bbnbs
```

Next, since we are using each term in `alist` to create terms from `blist`,
I use a `map` here.

```
mergeTupleList'''' as bbns = 
  let
    tupleAB ((b,bn):bs) (a,ab) = 
      if ab == b
         then (a, bn) : tupleAB bs (a,ab)
         else tupleAB bs (a,ab)
    tupleAB [] _ = []
  in concat $ map (tupleAB bbns) as
```

Finally, the inner `tupleAB` can be formulated as a `fold`; something that incrementally builds a data structure through an element-by-element decomposition of the list. The core logic of that fold is now held in `f`.

```
mergeTupleList''''' as bbns = 
  let
    tupleAB bs aab = foldr (f aab) [] bs
    f (a,ab) (b,bn) acc
       | ab == b        = (a,bn) : acc
       | otherwise      = acc
  in concat $ map (tupleAB bbns) as
```

I prefer where bindings to let bindings, stylistically. Alghouth there are memory performance issues I don't understand concerning the choice.

```
mergeTupleListW as bbns = concat $ map (tupleAB bbns) as
  where
    tupleAB bs aab = foldr (f aab) [] bs
    f (a,ab) (b,bn) acc
       | ab == b        = (a,bn) : acc
       | otherwise      = acc
```

Extra Credit. He is the function written as a List monad.

```
mergeTupleListM as bbns = 
  do a <- as
     tupleAB bbns a
  where
    tupleAB bs aab = foldr (f aab) [] bs
    f (a,ab) (b,bn) acc
       | ab == b        = (a,bn) : acc
       | otherwise      = acc
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me again! Actually I had no idea what I was doing with `:[ ] ++`

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered but here is what I figured out, with help from the comments. 
First we create a `groupByTwo`  function to break `listA` in lists containing each two elements.

```
groupByTwo [] = []
groupByTwo list = 
 (take 2 list) : (groupByTwo (drop 2 list))
```

Then we create a `mergeTupleList'` function to run the simple `mergeTupleList` on each element of the list of lists.

```
mergeTupleList' [] _ = []
mergeTupleList' (a:as) list2 =
  mergeTupleList a list2 ++ mergeTupleList' as list2
```

Finally a third function called `groupTupleMerge` to make life easier.

```
groupTupleMerge list1 list2 =
    mergeTupleList' (groupByTwo list1) list2
```